# MensageBox está em loop

Tags: c#, devexpress

Ao iniciar meu projeto `WinForms`eu defino o foco em um componente `lookUp Edit` do `DevExpress` que possuí um evento `Leave`. O objetivo deste foco é tornar obrigatório a seleção do destino. O valor inicial deste componente é `null` e é preenchido com dados do banco. Ao clicar em um outro elemento, por exemplo: um menu que está no form principal, é exibido um alerta porém este fica em loop. Eu preciso que após clicar em outro elemento, o alerta seja exibido e o foco volte no `lookup Edit destino`.

---

Ao meu ver, o loop acontece pelo fato do valor padrão do destino ser = `null` e após o `return` ele acaba caindo na mesma condição. Porém eu não consegui achar um meio de consertar isso

---

O valor padrão da variável `Encerrar é false` e o valor padrão do componente `destino é null`

---

Como posso resolver isso? Abaixo segue um fragmento do código.

```
 private void Destino_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Encerrar)
    {
        if (destino.EditValue == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Selecione um Destino");
            ActiveControl = destino;
            destino.Focus();
            return;
        }
         LugarDestino = destino.EditValue.ToString();


         ...restante do código...
    }
}
```

Comment: `Destino_Leave` parece ser um manipulador de evento. De que objeto esse manipulador assinou e que evento (quem é `sender`)? Essa ação `Leave` é o equivalente ao `LostFocus` dos controles default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após alguns testes notou-se que o evento `Leave` não era adequado para esta situação. O alerta era exibido toda vez que este evento acontecia e também pelo fato do valor padrão ser igual a `null`, ou seja, ao iniciar foco era atribuído no componente Destino entretanto pelo fato do seu valor padrão `Null` o alerta era exibido fazendo com que o evento `Leave` fosse acionado novamente causando o terrível `loop`...

A solução foi trocar o evento de `Leave` para `Validating` pois dessa maneira possibilitou validar o valor do componente Destino mesmo se o valor for `null`, posteriormente, exibido o alerta uma única vez. Em questão de usabilidade do sistema foi melhor trocar a função `Focus()` por `ShowPopup()`.

---

Abaixo segue o fragmento do código atualizado:

```
private void Destino_Validating(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (!Encerrar)
    {
        if (destino.EditValue == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Selecione um Destino");
            ActiveControl = destino;
            destino.ShowPopup();
            return;
        }
         LugarDestino = destino.EditValue.ToString();


         ...restante do código...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quando fui desenvolver usando devexpress, tive alguns problemas assim, então eu não usei mais o "focus", mas tenta com o código abaixo.

Acredito que ao usar o activecontrol e focus, o foco do objeto está sendo retirado e colocado, fazendo um loop eterno.

```
private void Destino_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Encerrar)
    {
        if (destino.EditValue == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Selecione um Destino");
            return;
        }
         LugarDestino = destino.EditValue.ToString();


         ...restante do código...
    }
}
```

Comment: Se remover o foco funciona, entretanto eu preciso que o foco seja obrigatório no componente, ou seja, quando eu clicar em um outro componente o alerta seja exibido e que o foco seja definido no componente... o problema é que dessa maneira, de focar o componente, fica em loop :(

Answer (score 0):

Assim que entrar no evento desativa ele, antes de sair ativa de novo.

```
    private void Destino_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //desativando o evento
        destino.Leave -= Destino_Leave;
        if (!Encerrar)
        {
            if (destino.EditValue == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Selecione um Destino");
                ActiveControl = destino;
                destino.Focus();
                return;
            }
            LugarDestino = destino.EditValue.ToString();
        }
        //ativando o evento
        destino.Leave += Destino_Leave;
    }
```

Comment: Oi Marcelo, obrigado pela ajuda, dessa maneira ao clicar em um outro componente o alerta é exibido uma vez, ao clicar uma segunda vez em outro componente o alerta não é exibido mais :(